# What does "what's the hangup?!" mean?

Tags: meaning

On this page: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645

There is a sentence:

> All these database servers allow this, so what's the hangup?!

What does `what's the hangup` mean?

Comment: Did you try to Google this term first?

Comment: Dear Yousui, look in Dictionary.com or Wiktionary, they both give good definitions

Comment: Thanks Thursagen. I tried to look it up in LDOCE and can't find a good definitions. I'll give it a try on Dictionary.com and Wikitionary.

Comment: @yousui: Make sure to look at informal/slang definitions too. In some cases, they are the meanings used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "hangup" in this context (doesn't refer to someone hanging-up the phone on you), but rather, has the [meaning of : (By Dictionary.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hang-up)

> a source of annoying difficulty or burden; impediment; snag:

Your example in view of the definition above, is asking what the problem is, seeing that all databases allow "PostgreSQL,MSSQL, Oracle", what's stopping everyone from doing something (I'm not quite sure what the something, but it's got to do with adding a new option or something similar) in the past *one year*.

Perhaps, it could have the alternative meaning of ["Psychological block"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hang-up), that is, someone's having problem accepting doing that "something" :

> Hang-up : a preoccupation, fixation, or psychological block; complex

This could also apply to your context, in that, the commentor is saying, as all databases allow "PostgreSQL,MSSQL, Oracle", what's the problem(in a psychological sense this time), that's stopping everyone for the past year from doing that "something?"